# Trying to sum up total cost from user input in defintion

Tags: python, loops, menu, multiple-choice

I am trying to build a menu for user . User must order min 3 items and after that needs to decide if want to keep ordering after or end it. I created while loop for that and now it's my question

- How can I sum up all prices for each choice?

I include user answer in definition otherwise my loop is not working as I wish... I need to sum up each choice of different prices that need to match positions from list I've created.

I tried if statement inside def, outside. Like if input answer will be = 1, then price will be 1,20 etc and tried to sum it up, would not work.
Many thanks for any help !

```
prices = [1.20,1.30,2.00,1.60,2.00,2.50,4.00,4.80,3.80,3.25,3.40,2.70,2.50,3.15,4.40] 

food_menu = ["sandwich","pizza","lemon cake","chips","salad","panini","yoghurt","pasta","bagel,"cheese wrap","cherry muffin","egg","blt","marmite sarnine","watermelon pieces"]

def order1():
  input("Please choose which treat you wish to order by typing its position number [1-15] and confirm with ENTER : ")
  input("Next item to order: ") 


def order2():
  input("Another item number to order: ")



if decision == "y":
  print ("Awesome! Let's get started!")
  order1()

i=1
x=""
while i>0:
  if decision == "y":
    order2()
    x = input("Keep adding more food for bigger discount?\ny - for yes\ns - for stop:\nYour answer: ")
    if (x == "s"):
      break
  elif decision == "n":
    print ("Please come back tomorrow or try again. Today you need to get minimum 3 items today!\U0001F641")
    print ("Bye bye!")
    i=0
    exit()
  else:
    print ("Wrong answer, please try again from the start.. \U0001F641 ")
    i=0
    exit()
```

After that I should sum up all the prices for each item that customer wants to order.

Comment: `order1` and `order2` are using `input` to RETRIEVE data from user, but you don't retrieve that value, why so ?because for now they are similar as `print` but you  need to type something for the program to continue each time

Comment: Can you detail the price part `Like if input answer will be = 1 then price will be 1,20` ?

Comment: @azro I meant here if user answer will be 1 (position on the list) then price = 1.20 . I tried to use it this way but would not work as I hoped

Comment: What list ? I don't see any

Comment: food_menu = ["sandwich","pizza","lemon cake","chips","salad","panini","yoghurt","pasta","bagel,"cheese wrap","cherry muffin","egg","blt","marmite sarnine","watermelon pieces"] , each item on the list match index number+1

Comment: And how do you determine the price ? I don't see any `1.20` ?

Comment: Sorry, I've created different list for that so I could use it for output for user

Comment: prices = [1.20,1.30,2.00,1.60,2.00,2.50,4.00,4.80,3.80,3.25,3.40,2.70,2.50,3.15,4.40]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add that, don't add important infos in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have one main loop, then 2 parts in it

1. handle choice of user for the product
2. handle choice for continuing or not

Also a `dict` is the best structure to store both menu and prices, and it provides easy acess and very test inclusion

```
food_menu = {'sandwich': 1.2, 'pizza': 1.3, 'lemon cake': 2.0, 'chips': 1.6, 'salad': 2.0, 'panini': 2.5,
             'yoghurt': 4.0, 'pasta': 4.8, 'bagel': 3.8, 'cheese wrap': 3.25, 'cherry muffin': 3.4, 'egg': 2.7,
             'blt': 2.5, 'marmite sarnine': 3.15, 'watermelon pieces': 4.4}

decision = ""
count = 0
total = 0
print("Menu with prices:")
print(*food_menu.items(), sep="\n")
while True:
    item = input("Please choose which treat you wish to order by typing its position number [1-15] "
                 "and confirm with ENTER : ")

    if item in food_menu:
        total += food_menu[item]
        count += 1
    else:
        print("Wrong input")

    decision = input("Keep adding more food for bigger discount? (y - for yes / s - for stop) : ")
    if decision == "s":
        if count < 3:
            print("Please come back tomorrow or try again. Today you need to get minimum 3 items today!")
        else:
            print("Total price is:", total)
        break
```

Comment: Makes much sense now! Really appreciate the code correction . I did not know about dict until now . Long way ahead! Thanks!